# Can't display plot of large numbers properly in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and ggplot. I have a set of large numbers and it seems that ggplot can't display it properly either with geom_bar() or geom_line(). Or  maybe I missed a few parameters that can adjust the scale of the plot. Please point it out. Thank you!

**For bar chart:**

Command:

`ggplot(income_exercise, aes(x= 'income2')) + geom_bar()`

Data: 
[image: data of income category and count of people in each category]

Problematic plot:

[image: each bar is oversized, ggplot can't adjust the scale automatically]

For line chart:

command:
`ggplot(income_exercise, aes(x= 'income2', y="cat_count")) + geom_line()`

problematic chart:

[image: not display any data]

Comment: Why `'income2'` in quotes? There is no need as such. Also `geom_bar` should have parameter `stat ="identity"`

Comment: Do not put your example data in as a picture. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Or, rather than `geom_bar`, use `geom_col` which automatically uses `stat="identity"`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(income=c('Less than 10k', 
                           'Less than 15k',
                           'Less than 20k'),
                 freq=c(25441,
                          26794,
                          34873))
# for bar chart
ggplot(df, aes(x=income, y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

# for lines
ggplot(df, aes(x=income, y=freq, group=1)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```